# Open app after installation from pkg file in Mac

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line-arguments, xcode7.1

I've created a SampleApp.app file from XCode 7.1 and converted it to pkg file and signed it using the product build command and it worked fine. But now the problem is, when I install the pkg the app does not start automatically after installation. Do I need to include any other arguments in my command to make this work? Below is the command that I use to create and sign the pkg.

```
productbuild --component SampleApp.app /Applications SampleApp.pkg

productsign --sign "Developer ID Installer: xxxxx" SampleApp.pkg SampleApp_signed.pkg
```

## EDIT

I've also tried to add a postinstall script but that didnt seem to work, I'm not sure if its the problem with my script or command

```
pkgbuild --root SampleApp.app --identifier com.companyname.SampleApp --scripts startup.sh --install-location /Applications/SampleApp.app SampleApp.pkg

productsign --sign "Developer ID Installer: xxxxx" SampleApp.pkg SampleApp_signed.pkg
```

**My startup.sh file**

```
#!/bin/bash

open -a /Applications/SampleApp.app

exit 0
```

Comment: what did you finally do to get this to work.  I am doing the very same as your edited post... even chmod executable the startup.sh file... but nothing ever happens for me. my commands and script are identical to yours except the app name and key name... the script just doesn't seem to run

Comment: never mind I got it.

Comment: @JasonReeves how you able to make it run? I chmod the .sh file and then attached in pkgbuild command but it never fires after installation done!

Comment: @SantanuKarar first, the file must be named postinstall.sh second, the --scripts path had to be the fully qualified path to the scrips folder i.e. /Projects/myproject/bin/scripts and make sure it points to the folder... not the file. then when you run pkgbuild, you will see in the console "adding postinstall script" (or something like that) and you will know you have it set up correctly!  Took me a while to figure this one out!!  Hope this helps!

Comment: This not worked for me strangely. My commands were: ``$ pkgbuild --root Helper.app --scripts "/Users/santanu/Documents/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/SVNBranch/Helper/build/Scripts" --install-location /Applications/Helper.app newBoot.pkg``. Following were my output - ``pkgbuild: Inferring bundle components from contents of Helper.app. 
pkgbuild: Adding component at Contents/Frameworks/Adobe AIR.framework. 
pkgbuild: Wrote package to newBoot.pkg`` - but these never starts postinstall script that I attached.

Comment: I also did chmod stuff to the postinstall file before pkgbuild, I also tried to expanding the pkg file ``pkgutil --expand newBoot.pkg expandedFolder`` and I confirm I had postinstall.sh file inside it's Scripts folder.

Comment: To keep a note, this finally worked for me. But following steps specifically worked for me. 1. Put a non-extension executable inside a folder and make sure it's must named ``preinstall`` or ``postinstall``. 2. Apply ``chmod 755`` and ``chmod a+x`` to the file, 3. No need to mention absolute path in ``pkgBuild`` command but point the folder containing ``postinstall`` script for ``--scripts`` field. Finally I received "Adding top-level postinstall script" result in my packaging.

Comment: @Gamerlegend  How can I create "My startup.sh file". Please help me.

Comment: @Giresh, if you are on mac, open terminal and choose any editor for eg:Enter  sudo vi startup.sh and press "i" and copy paste required content then press esc :wq, now make it executable by entering sudo chmod a+x startup.sh That's it!!!

Comment: Thanks @Gamerlegend

Comment: @Gamerlegend in my cash the app not opening after installing from .pkg file. Can you please give me details step by step process.

Comment: First u need to make your .sh file executable as I mentioned in my above comments then use the command given in the question to add postinstall script to pkg file. Just make sure your app opens by typing command: sh startup.sh in terminal. If it opens then you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you would create a `postinstall` script, and include it with the `--scripts` option.

**--scripts scripts-path**

> The contents of scripts-path is added to the product archive for use
>   by system.run() commands in the distribution.  This is valid only for
>   product archives targeted to the OS X Installer application.

So a (very) basic example of `postinstall` could launch an app by:

```
#!/bin/sh

open /path/to/your/app
exit 0
```

Comment: I've tried this but my app still doesn't open after installation, I dont get any errors while creating and signing the pkg, is there any problem with my script file? I'm on EI Capitan

Comment: I tried --scripts ./startup instead of startup.sh but says the file “startup” couldn’t be opened. And when I build with startup.sh it gets created but doesnt work. Any advice?

Comment: It was my mistake, I had to make the startup.sh file executable using chmod a+x startup command

Comment: @Gamerlegend: The script might need `root:wheel` ownership set (if not already or via pkgbuild), although might not matter if you're just opening the app.

Answer (score 2):

I had to use `sudo` in the `postinstall` script to get it to work:

```
#!/bin/sh

sudo open -a 'appName'

exit 0
```

Answer (score 2):

As [Santanu Karar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4227778/santanu-karar) mentioned in a comment:

> 1. Put a **non-extension** executable inside a folder and make sure it's must named **preinstall** or **postinstall**.

Note: **Not `postinstall.sh` but `postinstall`!**

> 2. Apply `chmod 755` and `chmod a+x` to the files preinstall and/or postinstall.
> 3. No need to mention the script's full path in the pkgBuild command. Point the **folder** containing postinstall script for the `--scripts` parameter.

As in `--scripts "./Scripts/"` and **not** `--scripts "./Scripts/postinstall"`

Lastly, it safer to use `open "$2/App Name.app/"` in  the script, as `$2` is the install location, and it's passed to the postinstall script.

Comment: In my case, `$2` is actually the install location **including* the `App Name.app` directory name.

Answer (score 2):

For many apps, you don't want to fire them up as sudo/root, so, you'll want to launch it as an ordinary user (e.g the one installing)

```
su "$USER" -c "open path/to/MyApp.app"
```

Note, there are many things in `pkgbuild` that are either undocumented, archived, or hard to find docs for online, such as `$2`, which is the path to the application you're installing.

This means you can also do this...

```
su "$USER" -c "open $2"
```

There are other variables as well, such as `INSTALLER_TEMP`, which I use in one of my scripts to know if a command line utility my app ships with is being run during install or during normal operation.  The variable isn't very useful otherwise.

Bitrot warning... At time of writing this, Google has [4 search results for `INSTALLER_TEMP pkgbuild`](https://www.google.com/search?q=INSTALLER_TEMP+pkgbuild) and GitHub turns up [one single result for some savenotes](https://github.com/karlredgate/doc/blob/a56fae8db88e796cf5b768aeedf0049e626f86f9/notes/OSX.md) so I feel it important to ask (and answer) and ultimately archive here so that there are secondary copies of these techniques.

Answer (score 0):

ok because OSX is so dumb and stupid, don't use application path instead use app name or bundle id because it seems OSX needs time to figure out that your application is actually an application:

you can open using bundle id:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

open -b 'com.myapp.mac'

exit 0
```

or open using app name:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

open -a 'MyApp'

exit 0
```